# Popup window not opening on IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

Hi Javascript gurus, I have this Javascript code which is working fine on Firefox , but it is not working on IE 7. Any ideas why?

Here is the code

```
function TestWindow()
{
     SimpleWindow('Default.aspx', 'Simple Test', 200, 200, 'yes')
}

function SimpleWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll)
{

    var win= null;

    var winl = (screen.width-w)/2;


    var wint = (screen.height-h)/2;

    settings='height='+h+',width='+w+',top='+wint+',left='+winl+',scrollbars='+scroll+',toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,dependent=no'

    win=window.open(mypage,myname,settings)

    if(parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4)
        {
            win.window.focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have realized that IE is giving the error "Invalid argument."

IE doesn't seem to like window names with spaces in them. Change 'Simple Test' to 'SimpleTest' etc.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I have your code in front of me, working after I changed the name to 'SimpleTest'.

Answer (score 4):

For *myname* parameter use only a-zA-Z0-9 characters. IE doesn't like any other, especially whitespace characters.

Comment: Are you sure that is the second parameters refers to the title of the page. So in IE7 it could not have space for the title?

Comment: @Shiva - that isn't the title of the page (that comes from the html), it's the name of the window.

Comment: yes, I'm sure of my answer. The second parameter of window.open is windows' name to which you can then refer in target attributes. It isn't the windows title.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked once I removed the whitespace characters from the title.

Answer (score 0):

Check popup blockers

Answer (score 0):

Check for reserved words. Your parameter name "scroll" is probably messing up your code in IE.