# Why this popup fail on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, popup

I have this code :

```
<a id="bookingLink" href="javascript.void(0);">Link</a>

$('#bookingLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    window.open("http://www.google.com", "Booking Daniela", "width=950,height=680");
});
```

and it fails (no popup is showed; also, the link in the bottom is /javascript.void(0);)

Why? And how can I fix it?

P.S. Popup are enabled on the browser :)

Comment: I'd try removing the `href` attribute. Or, at least, there shouldn't be dot after `javascript`; use colon instead.

Comment: Tried (removing the whole a and change it with a div) but the popup still unshow...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Popup window not opening on IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100320/popup-window-not-opening-on-ie7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not support "name" attribute, so if you delete "Booking Daniela", it will work

```
window.open('http://www.google.com', '', 'width=950,height=680');
```

Check the following MS documentation page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

**sName**

"Optional. String that specifies the name of the window. This name is used as the value for the TARGET attribute on a form or an anchor element."

Comment: It does support the name attribute, but it's very strict about it: no spaces allowed.

Comment: "This name is used as the value for the TARGET attribute on a form or an anchor element"

Comment: I can't think of a single way how that sentence could be interpreted as "this parameter has to be left empty".

Comment: I didn't write that it should be left empty, but MS treat this param as TARGET attribute. Anyhow, any value without space also works. I'm just giving reference regarding this behavior in IE.

Answer (score 3):

the name attribute must have no space. Try "BookingDaniela"

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
<a id="bookingLink" href="javascript.void(0);">Link</a>
$('#bookingLink').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
window.open("http://www.google.com", "Booking Daniela", "width=950,height=680");
});
```

Let's rewrite this to work:

```
<a id="bookinglink">Link</a>

$('#bookinglink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open("http://www.google.com","Booking Daniela", "width="950,height=680");
});
```

If you wanted to pass the data in (e.g. if you have multiple #bookinglink elements), you could do this:

```
<a id="bookinglink" pagename="link1">Link</a>
<a id="bookinglink" pagename="link2">Link</a>
<a id="bookinglink" pagename="link3">Link</a>

$('#bookinglink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var opage = "http://www.google.com";
    var pname = $(this).attr('pagename');
    window.open(opage,pname,"width=950,height=680");
});
```